# Atomic transactions in key-value stores

Tags: couchdb, transactions, cassandra, key-value

Please excuse any mistakes in terminology.  In particular, I am using relational database terms.

There are a number of persistent key-value stores, including [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) and [Cassandra](http://incubator.apache.org/cassandra/), along with plenty of other projects.

A typical argument against them is that they do not generally permit atomic transactions across multiple rows or tables.  I wonder if there's a general approach would would solve this issue.

Take for example the situation of a set of bank accounts.  How do we move money from one bank account to another?  If each bank account is a row, we want to update two rows as part of the same transaction, reducing the value in one and increasing the value in another.

One obvious approach is to have a separate table which describes transactions.  Then, moving money from one bank account to another consists of simply inserting a new row into this table.  We do not store the current balances of either of the two bank accounts and instead rely on summing up all the appropriate rows in the transactions table.  It is easy to imagine that this would be far too much work, however; a bank may have millions of transactions a day and an individual bank account may quickly have several thousand 'transactions' associated with it.

A number (all?) of key-value stores will 'roll back' an action if the underlying data has changed since you last grabbed it.  Possibly this could be used to simulate atomic transactions, then, as you could then indicate that a particular field is locked.  There are some obvious issues with this approach.

Any other ideas?  It is entirely possible that my approach is simply incorrect and I have not yet wrapped my brain around the new way of thinking.

Comment: CouchDB isn't key-value, it's a document store.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If, taking your example, you want to atomically update the value in a *single* document (row in relational terminology), you can do so in CouchDB. You will get a conflict error when you try to commit the change if an other contending client has updated the same document since you read it. You will then have to read the new value, update and re-try the commit. There is an indeterminate (possibly infinite if there is a *lot* of contention) number of times you may have to repeat this process, but you are guaranteed to have a document in the database with an atomically updated balance if your commit ever succeeds.

If you need to update two balances (i.e. a transfer from one account to an other), then you need to use a separate transaction document (effectively another table where rows are transactions) that stores the amount and the two accounts (in and out). This is a common bookkeeping practice, by the way. Since CouchDB computes views only as needed, it is actually still very efficient to compute the current amount in an account from the transactions that list that account. In CouchDB, you would use a map function that emitted the account number as key and the amount of the transaction (positive for incoming, negative for outgoing). Your reduce function would simply sum the values for each key, emitting the same key and total sum. You could then use a view with group=True to get the account balances, keyed by account number.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this.  You say that it is "still very efficient" to do a group.  Can you elaborate on this a bit?  For high-traffic relational databases, it is common practice to denormalise a column.  I can imagine that CouchDB and others store data significantly differently and this means the grouping of transactions could be more efficient.  But would you do this with 10 transactions to group?  100?  100,000?

Comment: CouchDB uses a Map/Reduce paradigm to view documents in the database. Since the map is applied only to changed documents, its (time) efficiency is essentially O(1) in the total number of documents, but O(n) in the number of changed documents. Reduced values are computed and stored in a b-tree. Obviously all nodes who have a child document that is changed will need to be recomputed. Thus it may be more time consuming to run the reduction. CouchDB has been demonstrated in production with many millions of documents so I don't think that will be an issue in this case.

Comment: Thank you.  By the way, I work for a social network site.  We aren't planning on switching to a persistent key-value store in the medium future.  We use sharded MySQL database servers and memcache, of course.  Looks like our busy tables have seen hundreds of millions of rows but nothing beyond that.  From your answers, it looks like CouchDB, at least, has been specifically designed to handle the sorts of issues I expect would come up for a site like ours.  Not too surprising but still good to hear.

I'm sure CouchDB and others would do some things better and the occasional thing worse.

Comment: I think I'd ammend your summary: "CouchDB and others would do some things better and some things worse". Damien Katz, the creator of CouchDB has often said that if your data would be described by documents (or cards or pages etc.) if it were physical, then CouchDB is a good match. If not (e.g. you're representing a graph of objects) CouchDB may be a very bad fit. It's just a tool, after all.

Comment: I've been interested in that question for a while and the answer is very helpful.
Can someone please complete the question by explain how eventually we will "commit" all the pending transactions. This is my understanding:
It is possible to treat each transaction as a separate document and have a view to calculate the balance of each account.
On a "night-job" we will take the database "offline" (not allow outside access) and process the transactions and update the actual balance of the account? Is that make the case close? Thank you,
Ido

Comment: It appears that CouchDB only guarantees conflicts if you run it in single-node configuration.

Comment: I have made a reference implementation (or canonical implementation for NodeJS) of proper single-document [CouchDB transactions](https://github.com/iriscouch/txn) in the fetch/modify/store cycle you describe. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 5):

CouchDB isn't suitable for transactional systems because it doesn't support locking and atomic operations.

In order to complete a bank transfer you must do a few things:

1. Validate the transaction, ensuring there are sufficient funds in the source account, that both accounts are open, not locked, and in good standing, and so on
2. Decrease the balance of the source account
3. Increase the balance of the destination account

If changes are made in between any of these steps the balance or status of the accounts, the transaction could become invalid after it is submitted which is a big problem in a system of this kind.

Even if you use the approach suggested above where you insert a "transfer" record and use a map/reduce view to calculate the final account balance, you have no way of ensuring that you don't overdraw the source account because there is still a race condition between checking the source account balance and inserting the transaction where two transactions could simultaneous be added after checking the balance.

So ... it's the wrong tool for the job.  CouchDB is probably good at a lot of things, but this is something that it really can not do.

EDIT: It's probably worth noting that actual banks in the real world use eventual consistency.  If you overdraw your bank account for long enough you get an overdraft fee.  If you were very good you might even be able to withdraw money from two different ATMs at almost the same time and overdraw your account because there's a race condition to check the balance, issue the money, and record the transaction.  When you deposit a check into your account they bump the balance but actually hold those funds for a period of time "just in case" the source account doesn't really have enough money.

Comment: This is demonstrably false: https://gist.github.com/wolever/1940301d4f7f530c0791 — it simply uses *different* (albeit significantly more complex) transaction model. While a "bank transfer" type application does require atomic operations (which couch has: document updates with a version check), locking is not required.

Answer (score 5):

To provide a concrete example (because there is a surprising lack of correct examples online): here's how to implement an "[atomic bank balance transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transaction_processing#Description)" in CouchDB (largely copied from my blog post on the same subject: http://blog.codekills.net/2014/03/13/atomic-bank-balance-transfer-with-couchdb/)

First, a brief recap of the problem: how can a banking system which allows
money to be transfered between accounts be designed so that there are no race
conditions which might leave invalid or nonsensical balances?

There are a few parts to this problem:

First: the transaction log. Instead of storing an account's balance in a single
record or document — `{"account": "Dave", "balance": 100}` — the account's
balance is calculated by summing up all the credits and debits to that account.
These credits and debits are stored in a transaction log, which might look
something like this:

```
{"from": "Dave", "to": "Alex", "amount": 50}
{"from": "Alex", "to": "Jane", "amount": 25}
```

And the CouchDB map-reduce functions to calculate the balance could look
something like this:

```
POST /transactions/balances
{
    "map": function(txn) {
        emit(txn.from, txn.amount * -1);
        emit(txn.to, txn.amount);
    },
    "reduce": function(keys, values) {
        return sum(values);
    }
}
```

For completeness, here is the list of balances:

```
GET /transactions/balances
{
    "rows": [
        {
            "key" : "Alex",
            "value" : 25
        },
        {
            "key" : "Dave",
            "value" : -50
        },
        {
            "key" : "Jane",
            "value" : 25
        }
    ],
    ...
}
```

But this leaves the obvious question: how are errors handled? What happens if
someone tries to make a transfer larger than their balance?

With CouchDB (and similar databases) this sort of business logic and error
handling must be implemented at the application level. Naively, such a function
might look like this:

```
def transfer(from_acct, to_acct, amount):
    txn_id = db.post("transactions", {"from": from_acct, "to": to_acct, "amount": amount})
    if db.get("transactions/balances") < 0:
        db.delete("transactions/" + txn_id)
        raise InsufficientFunds()
```

But notice that if the application crashes between inserting the transaction
and checking the updated balances the database will be left in an inconsistent
state: the sender may be left with a negative balance, and the recipient with
money that didn't previously exist:

```
// Initial balances: Alex: 25, Jane: 25
db.post("transactions", {"from": "Alex", "To": "Jane", "amount": 50}
// Current balances: Alex: -25, Jane: 75
```

How can this be fixed?

To make sure the system is never in an inconsistent state, two pieces of
information need to be added to each transaction:

1. The time the transaction was created (to ensure that there is a [strict
   total ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order#Strict_total_order) of transactions), and
2. A status — whether or not the transaction was successful.

There will also need to be two views — one which returns an account's available
balance (ie, the sum of all the "successful" transactions), and another which
returns the oldest "pending" transaction:

```
POST /transactions/balance-available
{
    "map": function(txn) {
        if (txn.status == "successful") {
            emit(txn.from, txn.amount * -1);
            emit(txn.to, txn.amount);
        }
    },
    "reduce": function(keys, values) {
        return sum(values);
    }
}

POST /transactions/oldest-pending
{
    "map": function(txn) {
        if (txn.status == "pending") {
            emit(txn._id, txn);
        }
    },
    "reduce": function(keys, values) {
        var oldest = values[0];
        values.forEach(function(txn) {
            if (txn.timestamp < oldest) {
                oldest = txn;
            }
        });
        return oldest;
    }

}
```

List of transfers might now look something like this:

```
{"from": "Alex", "to": "Dave", "amount": 100, "timestamp": 50, "status": "successful"}
{"from": "Dave", "to": "Jane", "amount": 200, "timestamp": 60, "status": "pending"}
```

Next, the application will need to have a function which can resolve
transactions by checking each pending transaction in order to verify that it is
valid, then updating its status from "pending" to either "successful" or
"rejected":

```
def resolve_transactions(target_timestamp):
    """ Resolves all transactions up to and including the transaction
        with timestamp `target_timestamp`. """
    while True:
        # Get the oldest transaction which is still pending
        txn = db.get("transactions/oldest-pending")
        if txn.timestamp > target_timestamp:
            # Stop once all of the transactions up until the one we're
            # interested in have been resolved.
            break

        # Then check to see if that transaction is valid
        if db.get("transactions/available-balance", id=txn.from) >= txn.amount:
            status = "successful"
        else:
            status = "rejected"

        # Then update the status of that transaction. Note that CouchDB
        # will check the "_rev" field, only performing the update if the
        # transaction hasn't already been updated.
        txn.status = status
        couch.put(txn)
```

Finally, the application code for *correctly* performing a transfer:

```
def transfer(from_acct, to_acct, amount):
    timestamp = time.time()
    txn = db.post("transactions", {
        "from": from_acct,
        "to": to_acct,
        "amount": amount,
        "status": "pending",
        "timestamp": timestamp,
    })
    resolve_transactions(timestamp)
    txn = couch.get("transactions/" + txn._id)
    if txn_status == "rejected":
        raise InsufficientFunds()
```

A couple of notes:

- For the sake of brevity, this specific implementation assumes some amount of
  atomicity in CouchDB's map-reduce. Updating the code so it does not rely on
  that assumption is left as an exercise to the reader.
- Master/master replication or CouchDB's document sync have not been taken into
  consideration. Master/master replication and sync make this problem
  significantly more difficult.
- In a real system, using `time()` might result in collisions, so using
  something with a bit more entropy might be a good idea; maybe `"%s-%s"
  %(time(), uuid())`, or using the document's `_id` in the ordering.
  Including the time is not strictly necessary, but it helps maintain a logical
  if multiple requests come in at about the same time.

Comment: This solution hypothesis is too incomplete for a system designed for master-master replication. In addition, even considering just one node, it does not show what must be done to recover after a node crash: What is done with all pending transactions upon restart?

Another issue is that is requires serial processing of all transactions, even if they do not touch the same accounts. This does not seem performant.

Also, it seems that all transactions need to stay forever in the system, thus growing the transaction log too much. How to handle this?

Comment: The answer to my questions is either impossible or too complex to justify the use of CouchDB for handling transactional operations on multiple documents.

Answer (score 1):

BerkeleyDB and LMDB are both key-value stores with support for ACID transactions. In BDB txns are optional while LMDB only operates transactionally.

Answer (score 1):

> A typical argument against them is that they do not generally permit atomic transactions across multiple rows or tables. I wonder if there's a general approach would would solve this issue.

A lot of modern data stores don't support atomic multi-key updates (transactions) out of the box but most of them provide primitives which allow you to build ACID client-side transactions.

If a data store supports per key linearizability and compare-and-swap or test-and-set operation then it's enough to implement serializable transactions. For example, this approach is used in [Google's Percolator](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/osdi10/tech/full_papers/Peng.pdf) and in [CockroachDB](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/blog/how-cockroachdb-distributes-atomic-transactions) database.

In my blog I created the [step-by-step visualization of serializable cross shard client-side transactions](http://rystsov.info/2016/03/02/cross-shard-txs.html), described the major use cases and provided links to the variants of the algorithm. I hope it will help you to understand how to implement them for you data store.

Among the data stores which support per key linearizability and CAS are:

- Cassandra with lightweight transactions
- Riak with consistent buckets
- RethinkDB
- ZooKeeper
- Etdc
- HBase
- DynamoDB
- MongoDB

By the way, if you're fine with Read Committed isolation level then it makes sense to take a look on [RAMP transactions](http://www.bailis.org/papers/ramp-sigmod2014.pdf) by Peter Bailis. They can be also implemented for the same set of data stores.